# Android: what does "Too many Binders sent to SYSTEM" mean?

Tags: android

This is a rare case, my app crashes suddenly without any crash dialog, there is neither a native crash log output in Logcat, but I see some strange log below:

[image]

It seems because of "Too many Binders sent to SYSTEM" and system kills my processes and restarts them. It happens only on one user's phone, cannot reproduce on other phones. We did not receive any report except that user.

I have no idea what may cause this issue. No result find after googling.

Comment: Can you show code please

Answer (score 2):

Our app encounters the same error when running on a Xiaomi Mi 8(MIUI 10.1.2.0, Android 9), but not other Xiaomi phones we have at hand. We're still finding the problem but it seems that it's related to a certain Google Play Services/Firebase lib.

If you need a quick fix, install Google Play Services on the phone and the crash is gone.

Will update the answer once we find out more.

Comment: yes, seems related to upgrading google firebase to latest version. Now we use 15.0.2/15.0.1 of google firebase, and it's ok. 16.0.x firebase have some issues

Answer (score 1):

My device (*Xiaomi 8, android 9.0*) encounters the same error too. I Integrated Google play service and Firebase lib:

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

But when my app runs on *Xiaomi 8* under *android 9.0 version*, everything is ok. And when I removed the related dependence about Filebase lib and run again on Xiaomi 8 with android 9.0, everything is ok too.

Comment: yes, seems related to upgrading google firebase to latest version. Now we use 15.0.2/15.0.1 of google firebase, and it's ok. 16.0.x firebase have some issues

Answer (score 1):

i add log at 'ContentService.registerContentObserver()' then build a debug rom that installed to my test phone. to print what uri and ContentObserver were registered too many.
the log result as follow:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We face same issue,
It seem work fine after upgrade crashlytics from 2.7 to 2.9.